# Published or widely known failures of Page Rank algorithm

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, searching

I use Google a lot for searching articles and publications. Occasionally, I find Google totally misses what I am looking for and I get completely unexpected results for some search queries.

> What are the published or widely known failures of PageRank algorithm?

EDIT: Changed the post to address comments.

Comment: Welcome to the IR world! :-) However reading your query *"difference" np complete* I cannot figure out what you are looking for, so I'm not surprised that the Google algorithm shows some *not-relevant* results, too :-) :-) However I suspect that Google is already using some personal information (e.g. profile info / openid usage / previous queries / results / clicks) to disambiguate the terms used.

Comment: Hi Marzio, I am looking for intractable problems that use some notion of "differncing" operation in their definition.

Comment: I also can't figure out what you would expect to get, even given that comment.

Comment: I don't think this is a failure in the PageRank algorithm. I think it is a failure in your google-fu :P. The word "difference" is very common, and is likely to come up in a good chunk of all papers even mentioning "NP-complete", so adding it to the query is useless. What you need to do is find a word, or alternate form of this word, that is very rare, and put it in quotes. For instance, "differencing" would be much rarer.

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany: as said by Realz, the word difference is too common and general even in computational complexity papers, so it is very difficult to get relevant results. You should use a better "search engine" ... for example a question on cs.stackexchange.com :-) :-)

Comment: @RealzSlaw When you search "P NP" you get very relevant results. Obviously, the query "difference NP complete" is far less common than "P NP".

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany my point was that the word "difference" is common and ambiguous, and the most common usage of it is not in your favor. I used the term "google-fu" in a joking manner, but it is a skill of trying to find a keyword that will differentiate the ambiguity in your favor (no pun intended). You obviously failed at google-fu with the word "difference": it will not differentiate the ambiguity well, because a good percentage of things talking about PvsNP or NP-complete things, will happen to have "difference" in them, and your results will be flooded with false-positives.

Comment: The edit merely removes a specific example and doesn't make the question any more precise or answerable.

Answer (score 2):

yes this "problem" is quite well studied and google itself is researching ways to improve it. its called the [word sense disambiguation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word-sense_disambiguation) problem and is under active/ongoing research, as its becoming a competitive feature between different search engines. quite simply, the same word has different meanings depending on context.

as for your more general question about "widely known failures of page rank", it is long known that it cannot necessarily distinguish [spam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_(electronic)) web pages designed to fool it, and a related technique called a [link farm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_farm) with many external pages pointing to one site. in this sense google search is employing somewhat similar aims/techniques to [spam-detecting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-spam_techniques) employed largely/widely by mail providers.

google has proprietary/closely guarded techniques to detect/filter spam and these are a large part of the continually refining versions released. then advertisers attempt to respond with new techniques. this back-and-forth [evolutionary dance/ "arms race"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coevolution) is also known as [search engine optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) from the advertisers pov, but the term also somewhat applies to googles process of improvement! (SEO is a very large field with strong overlap with marketing and probably worldwide worth in the billions of dollars.)

somewhat similar, so-called ["google bombing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_bomb) where people create a mass movement to use words together to affect search engine results. it is somewhat subjective whether to call this a "failure" of the search engine or actually a "feature" (as from the perspective of those exploiting it, because in a way search engines actually by design measure [meme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meme) prevalence in cyberspace!).

one method of dealing with word disambiguation is actually looking at trends in users personal search engine behaviors. in this way person A typing in a query will get different results than person B depending on their search histories.[1]

a related field called [Latent semantic analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis) helps with this somewhat by representing documents as sets-of-words with weights associated with each word, and the same word may have different weights in different documents or depending on document similarity measured by the [vector cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_cosine) technique.

an example paper from this field is K&M ref below. it actually uses & builds on results of *existing* google searches for word disambiguation.

yet another known issue is called "topic drift" where basically, if you search on two terms $x$ and $y$, if $y$ is more common it will tend to dominate and more results will be related to $y$ and "drown out" results with both $x$ and $y$. see eg [2]

- [Google, Bing Battle for Better Disambiguation, AI](http://www.eweek.com/search-engines/google-bing-battle-for-better-disambiguation-ai.html) eweek
- [Google & WordNet based Word Sense Disambiguation](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/suresh/www/IMG/pdf/wsd.pdf) Klapaftis, Manandhar
- [1] [Google Now Personalizes Everyone’s Search Results](http://searchengineland.com/google-now-personalizes-everyones-search-results-31195) searchengineland
- [2] [hits/pagerank & topic drift](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/18555/hits-and-pagerank-topic-drift-problem) tcs.se